# Oracle catch exception code given at runtime

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle12c

I want to create an Oracle PLSQL procedure that receives a statement that will be executed and a number representing a possible exception code that can arise and should be handled. I tried something but it doesn't compile 'PLS-00702: second argument to PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT must be a numeric literal'. Reading the docs about PRAGMA I understand why. How can I do this?

This is what I tried:

```sql
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE EXECUTE_AND_IGNORE_ERROR(dmlStatement IN VARCHAR2, oraErrorCode IN NUMBER) AS
    possibleException EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (possibleException, oraErrorCode);
BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE dmlStatement;
    EXCEPTION
       WHEN possibleException
       THEN
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Warning: Ignoring error [' || oraErrorCode ||'] after executing [' || dmlStatement || ']');
            NULL;
    END;
END EXECUTE_AND_IGNORE_ERROR;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Oracle requires literal parameters to the compiler directive `PRAGMA` because it's a compiler directive interpreted at compile time, not a function executed at runtime. Therefore you can't use it programmatically.

However, you shouldn't be trying to do this. Instead trap errors generically with `WHEN OTHERS THEN...` and consult either `SQLCODE`/`SQLERRM` or `dbms_utility.format_error_stack` and `dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace` for all the info you need.

Reserve `PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT` only for cases when there is a specific error you anticipate that you want to handle with its own exception handler block in a special manner, and that Oracle hasn't already assigned a common exception name for (e.g. `DUP_VAL_ON_INDEX`, `TOO_MANY_ROWS`, `NO_DATA_FOUND`). Those cover most errors, and `OTHERS` handles everything else. You won't need `PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT` very often.

Answer (score 3):

This seems like a bad idea and opens your database up to all sorts of SQL injection attacks. You should **NOT** use this on a production system or anything that takes unsanitised user input.

However, from a purely academic point-of-view, you can move the error handling into a statement that you evaluate using `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`:

```sql
CREATE PROCEDURE EXECUTE_AND_IGNORE_ERROR(
  dmlStatement IN VARCHAR2,
  oraErrorCode IN NUMBER
) AS
BEGIN
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE q'{DECLARE
    possibleException EXCEPTION;
    PRAGMA EXCEPTION_INIT (possibleException, }' || oraErrorCode || q'{);
  BEGIN
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE :1;
  EXCEPTION
     WHEN possibleException THEN
       DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(
         'Warning: Ignoring error [' || :2 || '] after executing [' || :3 || ']'
       );
       NULL;
  END;}'
  USING dmlStatement, oraErrorCode, dmlStatement;
END EXECUTE_AND_IGNORE_ERROR;
/
```

Then:

```
BEGIN
  DBMS_OUTPUT.ENABLE();
  EXECUTE_AND_IGNORE_ERROR('INSERT INTO does_not_exist (id) VALUES (1)', -942);
END;
/
```

Outputs:

> ```
> Warning: Ignoring error [-942] after executing [INSERT INTO does_not_exist (id) VALUES (1)]
> ```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/xKuziHb_)

Comment: Thanks, I'll be using this only with my own input statements so security is not an issue